# IPN handler Servlet never called

Tags: servlets, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've built a Java servlet to handle PayPal IPN calls, however the doPost function is never being called after payment, and the IPN status is always "retrying" and "failed".

I used a tool (Fiddler) to send a POST request to my servlet with the parameters from IPN history, and it worked!

Tried IPN simulator, and it also works well. Only PayPal itself doesn't call it.

The application runs in Amazon EC2 using Tomcat. Currently using PayPal sandbox.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried testing the IPN calls from the IPN Simulator? https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I wrote above: "Tried IPN simulator, and it also works well"

Comment: Hi there, did you sort this out?  I've got the same thing now; works from IPN simulator but not when I do a payment to a Sandbox Test Account, (with IPN configured)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it was solved after installing Linux updates and rebooting. Probably related to SSL certificate not working well before installing these updates and/or server restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after installing Linux updates and rebooting